# How to go to next or previous record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table named INV with records like the one below:

```
ID   | PROD      | WH | BRAND
200  |  0100760  | 01 |  ABC
100  |  010-1750 | 02 |  DEF
300  |  010-1750 | 01 |  SAM
4    |  1555     | 01 |  SAM
```

I am trying to use SQL(stored procedure) to go to next record in the database table.

Currently my sql is written like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 INV.*
FROM INV
WHERE INV.PROD > @prod
ORDER BY PROD ASC
```

Using the sql above, when `@prod` is 0100760, then it will go to the next record which has prod value of 010-1750  and wh value of 02

when I use the sql above but when `@prod` is 010-1750 it will go to the next record with prod value of 1555.

I want to change my sql statement into something like this(I am not sure) :

```
SELECT TOP 1 INV.*
FROM INV
WHERE

IF (INV.PROD = @prod) 
 INV.PROD = @prod 
 AND INV.WH <> @wh
ELSE 
 INV.PROD > @prod

ORDER BY PROD ASC
```

I think I need to use CASE inside my SQL query but I am not sure how. I cannot use ORDER BY ID.

Lets say I am at the record with ID 200. when I run the stored procedure, it should go to the record with ID 100. When I am record with ID 100, it should go to the record with ID 300

Comment: What's your expect result?

Comment: Then just `ORDER BY ID`, no?

Comment: @SalmanA. The records inside my actual database table is not like this. The ID column is not nicely in sequence.

Comment: What do you mean with "The ID column is not nicely in sequence"? Please update your sample data to reflect the actual problem. If you cannot use ID to sort by, then what is the "next" or "previous" record?

Comment: So it should select `010-1750,02` when you probe for `010-1750`?

Comment: @D-Shih. When I run my stored procedure with prod value = 0100760 and wh value = 01 it should go to record with the value of prod is 010-1750 and wh is 02. when I run my stored procedure with prod value = 010-1750 and wh value is 02 it should go to the record with value of prod is 010-1750 and wh is 01.... I cannot use order by id

Comment: The problem is, the column `prod` has duplicates. So when you say you want next record, after `010-1750` you have created a point of ambiguity. How can the system possible determine that which of the records with prod = `010-1750` are you refering to. This problem can be resolved by passing the previous id also as parameter so that you can know which id to look for next.

Comment: Note that id need not be sequential or increasing

Comment: Looking at your comment you will be stuck in an endless cycle... next for 0100760,01 is 0100760,02, next for 0100760,02 is 0100760,01. You'll never reach the 4th row.

Comment: It's generally better to use `AND`/`OR` constructions instead of `case` _expressions_ in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Take your original query. Add the @wh so you can distinguish cases, and add the new ID criterion to the order-by:

```
SELECT TOP 1 INV.*
FROM INV
WHERE INV.PROD > @prod or (INV.PROD=@prod and INV.WH > @wh)
ORDER BY PROD ASC,ID ASC
```

---

After looking throught the comments, I assume that each prod-wh combination is unique, therefore I consider them as a "key to be scanned". I changed the original `INV.WH <> @wh` of my answer to `INV.WH > @wh`, thanks to Sahil's observation. But be aware that this won't work if there are rows that have same BOTH prod and wh.

Comment: This will always give the lowest remaining id and would not work if wh has 3 values

Comment: Correct observation. I'll take a look to the comments again.

Answer (score 1):

You can find where the record exists in the table and then get the next record. The main point of ambiguity is that the list has partial ordering among its records and not total ordering. If we order the records according to the (prod, id) column(s), only then there will be a total ordering.

See if code below works.

```
SELECT TOP 1 INV.*
FROM INV
WHERE INV.PROD > @prod 
OR (
    INV.PROD=@prod 
    AND INV.ID > (SELECT ID FROM INV WHERE PROD + @prod AND WH = @wh)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code which may work for you and you can use as per your need. Use columns NextRecordID and PreviousID to fetch next record in your recursion.

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    ID      INT,
    PROD    VARCHAR(100),
    WH      VARCHAR(10),
    BRAND   VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO #Temp
SELECT 200,'0100760','01','ABC' UNION
SELECT 100,'010-1750','02','DEF' UNION
SELECT 300,'010-1750','01','SAM' UNION
SELECT 4,'1555','01','SAM' 

SELECT * FROM #Temp

SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN 
            LEAD(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY ID) IS NULL THEN -1 
        ELSE 
            LEAD(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY ID) END AS NextRecordID,
     CASE 
        WHEN 
            LAG(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY ID) IS NULL THEN -1 
        ELSE 
            LAG(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY ID ) END AS PreviousID,
    *
FROM 
    #Temp
ORDER BY 
    ID
```

Here is the output

[image]

Comment: You mean partition by Prod?

Comment: This implementation has problems because we want next `Prod` and not next id

Comment: by putting filter on ID column in where clause won't you able to get the prod?

Comment: Point in case next `PROD` after `1555` in your example